# How do you extend the constructor for a builtin like Object or Number?

Tags: javascript, prototype, primitive

Suppose I'd like to make all Numbers have property `foo` after they are made, containing something like the double of their value, for example. I'd like to do

```
// extend Number constructor here.
console.log(5.foo); // outputs 10
```

How do you do it?

Comment: Numbers are primitives. You can do it if you create an object, but why?

Comment: I don't know if it's possible, but it might be a really bad idea. Imagine someone reading your code, and saw somewhere using a `number.foo` variable, which is magically twice the value of the number. Wouldn't it be much more readable, if you write a method like `valueTwice(num)`?

Comment: Don't extend primitive objects, it's a really bad idea.

Comment: @elclanrs You mean I can only do it if I override Number then use `var num = new Number(5);`. Makes sense. I was hoping to do `console.log(5.foo); // outputs 10`.

Comment: TO be precise, it's incorrect to describe adding a prototype function as "overriding". It's "extending".

Comment: @torazaburo oops, yes, i used extend in the title.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't extend the constructor, but rather the prototype, by [defining a new property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty) on it, with a "getter":

```
Object.defineProperty(Number.prototype, 'foo', {
    get: function() { return this * 2; }
});

> 1.foo
  SyntaxError           // parser expected decimal part of number after dot
> (1).foo
  2
> 1..foo
  2
> 1.0.foo
  2
> Number(1).foo
  2
> new Number(1).foo
  2
> 1['foo']
  2
> 1e0.foo               // exponential notation
  2
> parseInt('1px').foo
  2
> 0x1.foo               // hex
  2
> 01.foo                // octal, disallowed in strict mode
  2
> Math.PI.foo
  6.283185307179586
> Infinity.foo
  Infinity
> NaN.foo
  NaN
```

Why does the first example `1.foo` fail? The JS parser, once it sees the dot, expects a decimal portion. There's no way around that. So you'll have to content yourself with saying `1.0.foo`.

But 1.0 is a primitive not an object, right? Then, how can `1.0.foo` possibly work? Because JavaScript will  coerce (cast, or transform) primitives to objects when necessary. In this case the numeric value is coerced to a number object just long enough to compute the value of `foo`, after which the object is thrown away (by garbage collection).

One might be tempted to also implement a setter, as in

```
set: function(v) { this = v/2; }
```

but of course this is invalid; we can't set `this`!! And there's no way to access the `[[PrimitiveValue]]` underlying the `Number` object to set it.

I do not recommend the above, It's not considered best practice to extend built-in types in this way. This is best placed in the realm of exotica.

Comment: But it's not possible to do 5.px?

Comment: You can also do `1..foo` but that just looks even weirder

Answer (score 1):

you need to extend the prototype:

```
Number.prototype.foo = function(){
return this*2;
}
```

Tho it's a method not a member.
    num = 2;
    num.foo(); //returns 4